# How to remove words, but leave the numbers?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that outputs like so:

```
string 'Filter with K1 upgrade (30L) - £445.00'
```

How can I remove all words and letters and just leave in the `445.00` number.

I could use `preg_replace()`, but I'm not sure of the syntax for it.

Comment: You need a few more examples to be sure of having the right pattern - is the bit you want always after a £ sign? Does it always have a . in the middle? etc (Note that you're not "leaving the numbers", because you're stripping the 1 of K1 and the 30 of 30L)

Comment: I only want the price which in this case is 445.00

Comment: For this single example, the function `function magic($string) { return '445.00'; }` would work, but I doubt that will help you. We need to see *multiple* examples, so we know what *pattern* we are trying to spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
$items = preg_split('/\s/', 'Filter with K1 upgrade (30L) - £445.00');
echo preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', array_pop($items));
```

Comment: That returns string '130445.00' but should be 445.00

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code:

```
var_dump(end(explode('£', $string)));
```

Comment: I've no idea if this actually meets the OP's requirements (I doubt it does), but it works for the single example currently given, so +1 for a technically valid answer.

Comment: If string every time had symbol £, then we can try use this example. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, yes, it might meet the requirements - it also depends if the price is always the last thing in the string. We just have no way of actually knowing that right now.